# port issue when sending POST with fetch to flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch, httpd.conf

**Little background of my situation:**

I have an app on my VPS with public IP. VPS is based on centOS7 and I want to send POST query via fetch from my JavaScript client to the server. From the server side I am using flask to receive POST data.

**Server side *httpd.conf*:**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/wet-pogotowie.pl">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://wet-pogotowie.pl"
    Allow from all
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

**Flask code:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def json():
  content = request.json
  return content

context = ('/var/.certs/cert.crt', '/var/.certs/priv.key')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host = 'wet-pogotowie.pl', port = 443, ssl_context = context, debug = True)
```

**JS's fetch:**

```
time = setInterval(function() {
  var zzz = {"xyz": "123"};
  const data = JSON.stringify(zzz);
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://wet-pogotowie.pl',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      crossorigin: true,
    },
  };

  fetch('https://wet-pogotowie.pl/api', options) // TU DZILA, NIE DZIALA Z PORTEM
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    // if everting is ok should log the object  message: "Long lang sent to express" from server
    console.log(data)
  });
}, 9000);
```

**The issue is:**
I cannot set port 443 in flask because ofcourse it's taken, but when I am trying to set other port in fetch - the 'SAME ORIGIN POLICY' - CORS error appears.

**My question:**
Where and what I need to change? Do I need to change something in my code or in server side?

**Additional info:**
When fetch is set to default 80 port - POST works, console log in browser shows it, but receiving 404 err.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed server from apache to nginx, here is the part of `nginx.conf` file:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  www.wet-pogotowie.pl;
        root         /var/www/html/www.wet-pogotowie.pl;
#   process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
         ssl_certificate "/var/.certs/cert.crt";
         ssl_certificate_key "/var/.certs/priv.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


    location /api
{
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
}

        proxy_pass https://www.wet-pogotowie.pl:3000;
    }
```

**main.js:**

```
time=setInterval(function(){
const data = "patrz wredny"
const options = {
    method: 'get',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'wet-pogotowie.pl',    
        'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'wet-pogotowie.pl',
        
    },
}
fetch('https://wet-pogotowie.pl:3000/api',options)
.then(response => response)
.then(data => {
    // if everting is ok should log the object  message: "Long lang sent to express" from server
    console.log(data)
});
  },9000);
```

Flask code is the same - only diff is port set to 3000 and SSL_CONTEXT enabled.
My point is - how to send or receive GET/POST from JS's front-end to python's flask?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few confused things here.

Generally your application doesn't listen on port 80 or port 443 directly, though it is certainly possible. In a shared hosting environment thooyg, it's surely very unlikely. Rather, you configure nginx (or I think that's Apache config you have there? Man I didn't realise people still used that) to reverse proxy to your python / node / ruby app. Your app listens on loop back port whatever you like, like 8080 or 9000 etc. You don't want to do SSL termination or static file hosting yourself, let nginx (or whatever) do that for you.

It's also not clear if you need the cross origin stuff. Is the website calling an api on the same domain?

The fetch call to port 80 "works" because nginx/apache tries to serve that URI but you get a 404 because (I'm guessing) you aren't routing traffic correctly to your back end python code.

Perhaps post more about which hosting, which httpd, and also what you've used in development.